# How can I reference my colors.xml file from Android Manifest meta tag?

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

This should be fairly simple, but yet I can't seem to find this.

I have my colors.xml file in `res/values` folder. Which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#10AAAA</color>
</resources>
```

Now, back in my `Android Manifest` file which is at the root of the project, I have the following meta-data tag relating to push notifications:

```
 <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@android:color/white"/>
```

Instead of the resource being `color/white` I would like to reference the `colorPrimary` from my `colors.xml` file. Can I do this? If so how?

I've already tried doing `android:resource="@android:color/colorPrimary`, but I get an error saying `colorPrimary` doesn't exist so there is definitely something missing.

Comment: android:resource="@color/colorPrimary"

Answer (score 3):

Solved it!
Reference it normally

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/colorprimary" />
```

But define colour lower case!

```
<color name="colorprimary">#3F51B5</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try `@color/colorPrimary`? `@android:color/XXX` means it belongs to the Android native color resource file, not your color resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@color/colorPrimary`

```
<meta-data
  android:name="your.name.com"
  android:resource="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```